# Git: выкачать промежуточную версию программы

Tags: git

Осваиваю git. Но до конца смысла его не понял. 
Возможно ли выкачать промежуточную версию программы? 
Или просто делал программу и тут решил, что все это не то, и нужно откатится на несколько коммитов и начать оттуда заново?

Кроме github, какие еще есть репозитории, чтоб можно было бесплатно размещать свои проекты приватно, или как можно создать свой репозиторий?

Comment: Думаю, что ответ на первую половину есть в этом вопросе: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431520/181472

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете получить любую версию вашего кода, просто откатившись до нужного коммита, например, так:

`git checkout -b <new_branch> <start_point>`

где

`new_branch` - имя локальной ветки;
`start_point` - идентификатор коммита, до которого вы хотите откатиться.

На тему аналогов github проще спросить в поиске. Навскидку вспоминается bitbucket и gitorious.

Comment: Вы запутываете человека. Ему не нужна новая ветка. `git checkout <commit_hash>` должно быть вполне достаточно.

Comment: @pirj Я не запутываю, по моему мнению, всегда лучше использовать новую ветку.

Comment: @pirj, если изменения еще не запушены, то как с них откатываться?

Comment: @pirji причем здесь другие люди, если речь в моем ответе идет о локальной ветке? Что потом с этой веткой делать - вопрос отдельный.

Comment: Вопрошающий интересуется, как ему откатиться, а вы предлагаете ему откатиться в новой ветке. Как думаете, не будет ли его следующим вопросом "я пушу на гитхаб, а в интерфейсе комита не видно", потому что он пушит в new_branch, а на GH основной веткой по-прежнему указан master? И что ему потом сделать, чтобы голова мастера потом указывала на голову new_branch? Не больше ли вопросов возникнет, чем проблем будет решено, если не советовать создавать новую ветку?

Comment: @pirj еще раз, пожалуй

> А стоит ли ту же новую ветку использовать тем людям, которые работают с вами вместе, в том случае, если вы ещё не пушили изменения

это как вообще возможно-то?

Comment: @Etki Пушил до последних изменений, которые захотел откатить, а после - не пушил. Пушнул новую ветку. "не пушили изменения" - имеется в виду master (старая основная ветка).

Comment: @pirj, если ее откатили до последнего незапушенного состояния, то она идентична мастеру в репозитории, в чем проблема-то?

Comment: @Etki Я вижу проблему в том, что дальнейшие комиты пойдут в new_branch, в то время как она не является основной.

Оригинально я спрашивал "зачем запутывать человека", и на этом же месте мы и остались. Зачем человеку, который не знает, как откатиться, прямо сейчас узнавать по другие ветки, мердж, отпочкования и прочее? Это как спрашивающему, как пройти в библиотеку, посоветовать сесть на метро. Так быстрее, если знаешь, как работает метро. А если не знаешь, то проще пройти по улице прямо два километра.

Answer (score 1):

По хостингам могу посоветовать https://bitbucket.org он тоже бесплатен как github , но фича в том, что на бесплатном тарифе можно сделать приватный репозиторий